# H2 database: How to list all views?

Tags: database, h2, database-view

What is a H2 command to list all views in the database?

I have expected that [`SHOW`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#show)  command would do the job but there is no option there to list views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are listed in the [information_schema](http://h2database.com/html/systemtables.html)

So, you need to run:

```
select *
from information_schema.views;
```

Comment: Thank you. For me it worked when I turned the tablename to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

please check [System Tables](http://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html) provided for H2 database engine under INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema

You can display all views by querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS system table

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and it should work.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as [View Name]
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

[H2 Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403875/how-to-see-all-tables-in-my-h2-database-at-localhost8082)